Fix skewed image when camera is rotated in three.js (R3F)
Here is a code snippet of what I have done so far
const Sphere = () => {
  // url is an panoramic image of type .png, jpeg, webp, or jpg.
  const texture = useLoader(THREE.TextureLoader, url);
  const sphereRef = useRef<THREE.Mesh>(null!);
  return (
    <mesh>
      <sphereGeometry args={[500, 60, 40]} />

      <meshStandardMaterial
        map={texture}
        side={THREE.Double}
      />
    </mesh>
  );
};

const Wrapper = () => {
  return (
    <>
      // lights
      <Controls /> (orbitControls)
      <Sphere />

       
    </>
  );
};

how do I made sure that when the camera is rotated, the image is not skewed
I have tried using useFrame with  sphereRef.current.lookAt(camera.position);
but the camera is not moving
